# RSSA package in R for windows

Tags: r, package, installation

I have used the Rssa package from cRAN in R using my mac computer and it install just fine. When I try to install it on my windows computer, it gives me this error

```
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘forecast’ is not available (for R version 3.0.1)
> install.packages("Rssa")

> library(Rssa)
Loading required package: forecast
Error: package ‘forecast’ could not be loaded
```

Does this mean the forecast dependency is not in the Rssa zip file in cran for windows? If so, is there a way around this or is it something else? I have tried googling this question but not much comes up for this package.

Comment: Did you try installing forecast?  What happened when you did?

Comment: I did try installing forecast by itself, this is what i got. > install.packages("forecast")
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘forecast’ is not available (for R version 3.0.1)
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/BaconDoggie/Documents/R/win-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘forecast’ is not available (for R version 3.0.1)

Comment: What version of R are you using? Just installed under Windows and R 3.0.2, everything is fine. Try a fresh R install maybe?

Comment: In that case please accept the answer below to mark this question as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recent 5.0 release of `forecast` package is only available for R (≥ 3.0.2). This package is listed in depends to `Rssa`, so you will have this problem under R 3.0.0 and 3.0.1.

Update your R, and everything will be fine. Another option in to manually install `forecast`, but that is not recommended.

I've contacted package maintainer, and he is working on either explicitly specify dependency on R (≥ 3.0.2) or moving `forecast` to suggests instead of depends. This issue will be resolved in the nearest future.